# proper implementation of ternary operator

Tags: javascript

EDIT: original code is now below.

When I make certain modifications to the ternary operator, I get that the memory property of network.optimized, in the web-worker I am using with this function, can't be called because optimized is null. I know it is not an issue with the web-worker because as soon as I remove my additions, the code works fine ( original ternary and worker).

I know the code is messy ( original code is now below ), but when I try to make my additions to the beautified version with if statements instead of ternary, there are all sorts of errors from this function. Even without my additions.

I've tried as much debugging as I know and the null error is due to my additions.

These are the additions that I was trying to make:

1.) `j !== undefined && j instanceof jay ? j.recursive(function(){r(t[l].input)}) : r(t[l].input)` which was supposed to be

```
if(j!== undefined && j instanceof jay) j.recursive(function(){r(t[l].input)})
else r(t[l].input);
```

2.) `j !== undefined && j instanceof jay ? j.recursive(function(){l++}, false) : l++` which was supposed to be

```
if(j !== undefined && j instanceof jay) j.recursive(function(){l++}, false)
else l++
```

3.) `j !== undefined && j instanceof jay ? j.recursive(function(){r(t[l].input)}) : r(t[l].input);` which was supposed to be

```
if(j !== undefined && j instanceof jay) j.recursive(function(){r(t[l].input)})
else r(t[l].input);
```

These seem logically correct to me, but I am doing something wrong that causes the worker's initiation to become messed up. Below is the whole onmessage function for the worker.

**Edit: Full code now below**

```
workerTrain: function(set, callback, options, z) {

                var that = this; 
                var error = 1;
                var iterations = bucketSize = 0;
                var input, output, target, currentRate;
                var length = set.length;

                var start = Date.now();

                if (options) {
                  if (options.shuffle) {
                    //+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
                    //@ http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle [v1.0]
                    function shuffle(o) { //v1.0
                      for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() *
                          i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
                      return o;
                    };
                  }
                  if (options.iterations)
                    this.iterations = options.iterations;
                  if (options.error)
                    this.error = options.error;
                  if (options.rate)
                    this.rate = options.rate;
                  if (options.cost)
                    this.cost = options.cost;
                  if (options.schedule)
                    this.schedule = options.schedule;
                  if (options.customLog)
                    // for backward compatibility with code that used customLog
                    console.log('Deprecated: use schedule instead of customLog')
                    this.schedule = options.customLog;
                }

                // dynamic learning rate
                currentRate = this.rate;
                if(Array.isArray(this.rate)) {
                  bucketSize = Math.floor(this.iterations / this.rate.length);
                }

                // create a worker
                var worker = this.network.worker();

                // activate the network
                function activateWorker(input)
                {
                    worker.postMessage({ 
                        action: "activate",
                        input: input,
                        memoryBuffer: that.network.optimized.memory
                    }, [that.network.optimized.memory.buffer]);
                }

                // backpropagate the network
                function propagateWorker(target){
                    if(bucketSize > 0) {
                      var currentBucket = Math.floor(iterations / bucketSize);
                      currentRate = this.rate[currentBucket];
                    }
                    worker.postMessage({ 
                        action: "propagate",
                        target: target,
                        rate: currentRate,
                        memoryBuffer: that.network.optimized.memory
                    }, [that.network.optimized.memory.buffer]);
                }

                // train the worker
                worker.onmessage = function(e){
                    // give control of the memory back to the network
                    that.network.optimized.ownership(e.data.memoryBuffer);

                    if (e.data.action == "propagate")
                    {
                        if (index >= length)
                        {
                            index = 0;
                            iterations++;
                            error /= set.length;

                            // log
                            if (options) {
                              if (this.schedule && this.schedule.every && iterations % this.schedule.every == 0)
                                abort_training = this.schedule.do({
                                  error: error,
                                  iterations: iterations
                                });
                              else if (options.log && iterations % options.log == 0) {
                                console.log('iterations', iterations, 'error', error);
                              };
                              if (options.shuffle)
                                shuffle(set);
                            }

                            if (!abort_training && iterations < that.iterations && error > that.error)
                            {
                                activateWorker(set[index].input);
                            } else {
                                // callback
                                callback({
                                  error: error,
                                  iterations: iterations,
                                  time: Date.now() - start
                                })
                            }
                            error = 0;
                        } else if(z!==undefined && z instanceof jay) z.recursive(function(){
                            activateWorker(set[index].input)
                        });
                        else activateWorker(set[index].input);
                    }

                    if (e.data.action == "activate")
                    {
                        error += that.cost(set[index].output, e.data.output);
                        propagateWorker(set[index].output);
                        if(z !== undefined && z instanceof jay) z.recursive(function(){index++}, false);
                        else index++;
                    }
                }

                // kick it
                var index = 0;
                var iterations = 0;
                if(z!==undefined && z instanceof jay) z.recursive(function(){activateWorker(set[index].input)});
                else activateWorker(set[index].input);
              },
```

Comment: I think you should rework your code before to have someone to look at it.
Maybe try to post the original function and your integral version instead of that sort of diff you gave us. It is already a mess, you already know, spare us some work and help us to help you

Comment: @Eineki clean code is there now at the bottom

Comment: Your problem is operator precedence - put parentheses around things. "clean code" <- ?

Comment: @AD7six oh, I usually put too many parentheses. Must have been when I was removing them. Can you put that as the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30738240/3743069

Comment: Why do you have two open questions about the same fundamental problem?

Comment: @AD7six one is with the issue with the compressed code and the ternary causing it and the other is not. I will close or select an answer when I get a solution. I guess it is not right. I can close this one. Do you have a solution?